# How to skip specific key value pairs in ngFor when using keyvalue pipe in angular

Tags: angular, pipe, key-value

I want to skip Date & Microsite key and value in item object while iterating using `ngFor`. So for `ngIf` is not working.

Here is my template

```
<table *ngIf="!emptyQueries">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Microsite</th>
        <th><div class="w-50 d-inline-block" >Query</div><div class="w-50 d-inline-block">Answer</div></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let item of queries">
      <td class="align-top">{{item?.Date}}</td>
      <td class="align-top">{{item?.Microsite}}</td>
      <td class="align-top">
          <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let entry of item | keyvalue">
                  <td class="w-50 align-top pt-0" *ngIf="entry.key != 'Date' || entry.key !='Microsite'">{{entry.key}}</td>
                  <td class="w-50 align-top pt-0" *ngIf="entry.key != 'Date' || entry.key !='Microsite'">{{entry.value}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is the actual output [image: output]

Any Idea how this can be solved? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `||` with `&&`:

```
*ngIf="entry.key != 'Date' && entry.key !='Microsite'"
```

Comment: ahh my bad :/ thanks for pointing out. What are careless mistake i made

Comment: Happens... Been through it :D

Comment: :D haha so that's normal i guess. I was feeling shameful

Comment: Absolutely normal :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in typescript using destructuration like :

```js
const {Date, Microsite, ...filtredItem} = item;
```

and then use `filtredItem` in your template without using `if`